# How to delete files stored in a cmake list in an add_custom_target?

Tags: cmake

I have files stored in a list variable `MatrixSSL_configure_files`.

I'd like to remove all files in a `add_custom_target`, like so

```
add_custom_target( maintainer-clean-evio
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E remove -f "${MatrixSSL_configure_files}"
)
```

This doesn't work because the list is semi-colon separated and the
list isn't expanded (the COMMAND simply tries to execute the files).

Of course I also tried

```
COMMAND rm -f ${MatrixSSL_configure_files}
```

with the same result.

Assuming the file names contain spaces, what would be the correct
way to do this? If not possible, assume they don't contain spaces :/

Comment: You second attempt - `COMMAND rm -f ${MatrixSSL_configure_files}` - should work. Like the first attempt with removed double quotes. Please, show example of content of the `MatrixSSL_configure_files` or example how do you initialize it: it could be that your list is somehow specific one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is precisely what the `COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS` option is for. From the [`add_custom_target`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html) documentation:

> `COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS`
>
> Lists in `COMMAND` arguments will be expanded, including those created with generator expressions, allowing `COMMAND` arguments such as `${CC} "-I$<JOIN:$<TARGET_PROPERTY:foo,INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>,;-I>" foo.cc` to be properly expanded.

So something like this should allow the `MatrixSSL_configure_files` list to be expanded:

```
add_custom_target( maintainer-clean-evio
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E remove -f "${MatrixSSL_configure_files}"
  COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I take it that this also works? Seems more straight forward than firing up another cmake: `COMMAND /bin/rm -f "${MatrixSSL_configure_files}" COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS`

Comment: @CarloWood Yes, it should expand the list in that case as well.

Comment: Thanks again! Final working result: https://github.com/CarloWood/evio/blob/master/protocol/CMakeLists.txt#L101